# How can I use php to get data from multiple .csv files, then compile that data and make an interactive visual to represent them?

Tags: php

Graphs will not work, because each file has thousands of rows and columns.
I have an assignment. My teacher has given me about four to five csv files, contain data on loans. Each .csv file has thousands of rows and columns. I know how to represent the data from one file in a table, but that is the full extent of my knowledge.

```
 <?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("LoanStats3a.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
```

I am required to create and interactive visual to represent that data, such as moving the mouse or clicking it does something.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pagination using dataTables to better representation even in thousands rows and columns.

Try this!

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#table').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100, -1], [10, 50, 100,"All"]],
        "pageLength": 10,
        "order": [[ 0, "" ]]
        }); 
} );
</script>
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Field Name</th>
            <th>Field Name</th>
            <th>Field Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
     <?php
        $f = fopen("LoanStats3a.csv", "r");
        while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell[0]) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell[1]) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell[2]) . "</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
    fclose($f);
    ?>                              
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Im getting the following error:"Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 2 in E:\wamp\www\Loans\index.php on line 34"